# Would this mutex implementation make sense in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, synchronization, mutex

I Need to implement synchronization between database sessions in PostgreSQL.

In SQL Server, I would implement it by creating my own "locking" table.

```
Create table MyLock(LockName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE, LockOwner INT NULL)
```

I do not use explicit transaction to avoid really locking things up, I would acquire my "singleton" lock by putting my session Id as "owner".

```
UPDATE MyLock
  SET LockOwner = *MySessionId*
  WHERE LockName = 'Singleton' 
  AND LockOwner IS NULL;
```

By not using explicit transactions, I am not holding up other processes.
You could think of this as "soft lock"...

If my update succeeds, then I know I "have" the lock and I can process some bit of code while other(s) would wait.
If my update updated nothing, I know someone else has the "lock" and I wait, or give up.

I need to implement something similar in PostgreSQL.

Would you do it like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, I would do it differently.

The problem is that you need to keep polling the lock, which means unnecessarily wasted CPU time or longer waits than necessary.

This requirement is perfect for PostgreSQL's [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS):

Instead of a lock name like `Singleton` you pick a lock number, e.g. 1234.

To obtain the lock, run

```
SELECT pg_advisory_lock(1234);
```

To release the lock, run

```
SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(1234);
```

This works just like normal database locks do, by suspending the calling process if the lock is unavailable and resuming it as soon as the lock holder releases the lock. There are also functions to “poll” an advisory lock for availability without blocking.

These locks are independent of PostgreSQL's transactions, they are held until released or untill the database session ends (so there is no danger of an “orphaned lock”).

These locks also don't interfere with autovacuum operations.

This is the perfect tool if an application wants to synchronize using database techniques.

Comment: If the "client" software does some sort of connection pooling, do we have a potential risk of inadvertently passing over session advisory locks if we don't explicitly  release them?

Comment: Yes, they are tied to a session.

Comment: How would one handle a client crashing in this case? In my case, I have a JDBC connection pool, and when a client crashes the connection is just returned to the pool, thus not closing the session and not releasing the lock.

Comment: Connection pools typically send a "cleanup" statement on each connection when it is returned to the pool. Use that.

Comment: Mind helping me with how this mechanism is called in JDBC? I'm afraid I cannot find it, or lack the correct vocabulary to search for it.

Comment: I guess it depends on the application server you are using, it is not part of JDBC. I don't know details about either.